# Laptop solid state hdd in deskop possible

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, computer-building

I've got an extra 2.5 inch 16GB SSD hard-drive. Not very big but I thought it would be perfect for my dad's PC. He's always complaining about it being slow. The processor is already a fast AMD CPU (can't quite remember which one).

I was wondering could I just wack it in his desktop? I know I'll need a bracket to convert up to 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the SSD will work fine in a desktop machine. As long as the motherboard is new enough to have SATA connections, you won't have a problem.

Still, this is not the first move I'd make to improve the performance of the machine. It may be more hassle than it's worth.

- 16GB is small...It'll work for a system drive to run the OS but it's too small to hold additional programs and applications. Remember you always need some free space breathing room for swap and temporary files.
- About the only thing I'd use a 16GB drive for is OS swap and Photoshop swap files. That's it. Maybe a replacement netbook drive.
- You are likely to get better performance increases (and save yourself a ton of re-installation time) by clearing out bloatware and startup items. Then defrag (but don't defrag an SSD).

Comment: why not? what's so special about an ssd ?

Comment: Defragmenting a disk reorganizes files in sequential order for faster mechanical reads. Since SSDs have such fast random access times, file ordering on the drive doesn't matter. Worse: the act of defragmenting and moving all the data around just wears the memory cells. [read more](http://superuser.com/questions/200791/do-i-need-to-run-defrag-on-an-ssd)

Answer (score 2):

Yep.  Should be absolutely no problem.  Sata connections are the same.

Are you sure there isnt another bottleneck however?