# Is there any use at all to defragmenting a solid state drive?

Tags: ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to run defrag on an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/200791/do-i-need-to-run-defrag-on-an-ssd)

Someone was asking me if it's at all useful to defrag a solid state. I'm assuming files get fragmented to different parts of the hardrive, but will that actually be bad when the access is so different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[No](http://www.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/CS-029623.htm#5)