# Defraggler left some spots at the end of my SSD

Tags: windows, defragment

Initially, I wanted to make a dual boot with Linux on my laptop and to accomplish that I had to shrink my `C:` Partition.

I couldn't do that because there was just ~6 GB of space to shrink, so for that I figured, that I would have to defrag my `C:` SSD.

I was aware that defragmenting a SSD isn't a good idea, but I didn't see any other possibility than that, if there is something else I could have done, than this would also be interesting.

Defraggler defragged my SSD quite nicely but it left some spots of data right at the "end" of my SSD and my available shrinking size isn't bigger now.

I would like to know what is the reason for these spots and how I can get rid of them.

This is how the Defraggler analyzes looks, after the defragmentation has been completed:

[image: This is how the defragger analyzes looks, after the defragmentation has been completed.]

Comment: What program did you use to defrag?

Comment: @bolov That's not exactly correct. How much a partition can be shrunk is limited by two factors: the position of the last byte in use and your tool's ability to move filesystem data around. If the latter is not supported then your partition can't be made shorter than the position of the last byte is use, because otherwise you would cut off some data. The "right" solution would be to use better tools, but still, defragmenting would also help, so it's not completely unrelated.

Comment: my bad, you are right. Even so, defragmenting is under no obligation to move the last piece and can in theory even move fragments to the end of the partition.

Comment: @DavidPostill it looks like Piriform's Defraggler.

Comment: Relevant: don't Defrag your SSD. Defragging SSDs does not improve performance and does damage them by excessive and unnecessary wear: https://superuser.com/questions/200791/do-i-need-to-run-defrag-on-an-ssd

Comment: Unfortunately you're not saying which OS and filesystem you are running. NTFS on windows allow for partition shrinking based on free space without the need to defrag for example.

Comment: Yes, but the free space is often limited, because the physical data on a SSD is distributed over the whole SDD dafter some years of use and then you have to defrag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is the reason for these spots and how I can get rid of them?

The "spots" are (fragments) of files that cannot be moved during normal use as they are locked by running applications or Windows.

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ White      ║ Empty                          ║ There is no data in this section of the hard drive.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Light Blue ║ Not fragmented (Low Occupancy) ║ This section is not fragmented, and does not contain a lot of data.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Blue       ║ Not fragmented                 ║ This section is not fragmented.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Light Red  ║ Fragmented (Low Occupancy)     ║ This  section is fragmented, and does not contain a lot of data. Files using  this section are also using other sections to store other file parts.                                                                                                                                                   ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Red        ║ Fragmented                     ║ This section is fragmented. Files using this section are also using other sections to store other file parts.                                                                                                                                                                                         ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Gold       ║ Page File                      ║ The  page file (or swap file) is a space on the hard drive which Windows  uses as an extension of its real memory (RAM). While Windows is running,  you cannot defragment this section of the hard drive.                                                                                             ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Purple     ║ Reserved MFT Space             ║ This  section is reserved for the Master File Table (MFT), which is a  database that stores information about every file and folder on this  hard drive. The MFT is used for NTFS-formatted drives only. Defraggler  can defragment the MFT as well, but it cannot move the MFT's starting  position. ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Yellow     ║ Files being read               ║ When  Defraggler is defragging a drive, you will see sections flash yellow as  it works. This indicates it is reading files from that section.                                                                                                                                                        ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Green      ║ Files being written            ║ Similarly, when Defraggler is defragging a drive, sections will flash green as it is writing files to them.                                                                                                                                                                                           ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Source: [Understanding the Drive Map in Defraggler – CCleaner Support](https://support.piriform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048669071-Understanding-the-Drive-Map-in-Defraggler)

You can try to run the defrag at boot time:

> **Boot Time Defrag with Defraggler**
>
> Defraggler has a Boot-Time Defrag option which allows you to defrag
> files that are normally locked by the Operating System before the
> operating system is fully loaded.
>
> To enable Boot-Time defrag:
>
> - In Defraggler’s main menu, click Settings, and then click Boot Time Defrag.
> - You can select the following run options:
> - Disabled – disable this option
> - Run Once – defrags files during boot time only once
> - Run Every Time – defrags files during boot time every time you start your PC
>   When you enable this option a dialog box will be displayed to inform you that this option has been switched on and ask you whether
>   you would like to reboot your PC now. If you choose Yes, your PC will
>   be rebooted and defragged. If you choose No, your PC will be defragged
>   upon the next reboot.
>
> At the moment following files are defragmented during the boot time defrag:
>
> ```
> C:\pagefile.sys
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\AppEvent.Evt
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\default
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\SAM
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\SecEvent.Evt
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\SECURITY
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\software
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\SysEvent.Evt
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\system
> ```

Source: [Boot Time Defrag with Defraggler – CCleaner Support](https://support.piriform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048672371)

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Additionally, I just disabled system restore, hibernation and page files.